# Loading TradingView in-line in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, tradingview-api

I am trying to load a TradingView chart using React by making use of the following:

`useScript.js`

```
export type Status = 'idle' | 'loading' | 'ready' | 'error'
export type ScriptElt = HTMLScriptElement | null

function useScript(src: string): Status {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState<Status>(src ? 'loading' : 'idle')

  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (!src) {
        setStatus('idle')
        return
      }

      // Fetch existing script element by src
      // It may have been added by another instance of this hook
      let script: ScriptElt = document.querySelector(`script[src="${src}"]`)

      if (!script) {
        // Create script
        script = document.createElement('script')
        script.src = src
        script.async = true
        script.setAttribute('data-status', 'loading')
        // Add script to document body
        document.body.appendChild(script)

        // Store status in attribute on script
        // This can be read by other instances of this hook
        const setAttributeFromEvent = (event: Event) => {
          script?.setAttribute('data-status', event.type === 'load' ? 'ready' : 'error')
        }

        script.addEventListener('load', setAttributeFromEvent)
        script.addEventListener('error', setAttributeFromEvent)
      } else {
        // Grab existing script status from attribute and set to state.
        setStatus(script.getAttribute('data-status') as Status)
      }

      // Script event handler to update status in state
      // Note: Even if the script already exists we still need to add
      // event handlers to update the state for *this* hook instance.
      const setStateFromEvent = (event: Event) => {
        setStatus(event.type === 'load' ? 'ready' : 'error')
      }

      // Add event listeners
      script.addEventListener('load', setStateFromEvent)
      script.addEventListener('error', setStateFromEvent)

      // Remove event listeners on cleanup
      // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
      return () => {
        if (script) {
          script.removeEventListener('load', setStateFromEvent)
          script.removeEventListener('error', setStateFromEvent)
        }
      }
    },
    [src], // Only re-run effect if script src changes
  )

  return status
}

export default useScript
```

The TradingView component that I'm attempting to load:

`TradingView.tsx`

```
import { useTranslation } from 'contexts/Localization'
import useScript from 'hooks/useScript'
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { DefaultTheme, useTheme } from 'styled-components'

/**
 * When the script tag is injected the TradingView object is not immediately
 * available on the window. So we listen for when it gets set
 */
const tradingViewListener = async () =>
  new Promise<void>((resolve) =>
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'TradingView', {
      configurable: true,
      set(value) {
        this.tv = value
        resolve(value)
      },
    }),
  )

const initializeTradingView = (TradingViewObj: any, theme: DefaultTheme, localeCode: string, opts: any) => {
  let timezone = 'Etc/UTC'
  try {
    timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
  } catch (e) {
    // noop
  }
  /* eslint-disable new-cap */
  /* eslint-disable no-new */
  // @ts-ignore
  return new TradingViewObj.widget({
    // Advanced Chart Widget uses the legacy embedding scheme,
    // an id property should be specified in the settings object
    id: opts.container_id,
    autosize: true,
    height: '100%',
    symbol: 'BINANCE:BNBUSDT',
    interval: '5',
    timezone,
    theme: theme.isDark ? 'dark' : 'light',
    style: '1',
    locale: localeCode,
    toolbar_bg: '#f1f3f6',
    enable_publishing: false,
    allow_symbol_change: true,
    hide_side_toolbar: false,
    enabled_features: ['header_fullscreen_button'],
    ...opts,
  })
}

interface TradingViewProps {
  id: string
  symbol: string
}

const TradingView = ({ id, symbol }: TradingViewProps) => {
  const { currentLanguage } = useTranslation()
  const theme = useTheme()
  const widgetRef = useRef<any>()
  const { isMobile } = useMatchBreakpoints()

  useScript('https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js')

  useEffect(() => {
    const opts: any = {
      container_id: id,
      symbol,
    }

    if (isMobile) {
      opts.hide_side_toolbar = true
    }

    // @ts-ignore
    if (window.tv) {
      // @ts-ignore
      widgetRef.current = initializeTradingView(window.tv, theme, currentLanguage.code, opts)
    } else {
      tradingViewListener().then((tv) => {
        widgetRef.current = initializeTradingView(tv, theme, currentLanguage.code, opts)
      })
    }

    // Ignore isMobile to avoid re-render TV
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [theme, currentLanguage, id, symbol])

  return (
    <Box overflow="hidden" className="tradingview_container">
      <div id={id} />
    </Box>
  )
}

export function useTradingViewEvent({
  id,
  onNoDataEvent,
  onLoadedEvent,
}: {
  id?: string
  onNoDataEvent?: () => void
  onLoadedEvent?: () => void
}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const onNoDataAvailable = (event: MessageEvent) => {
      const payload = event.data

      if (payload.name === 'tv-widget-no-data') {
        if (id && payload.frameElementId === id) {
          onNoDataEvent?.()
        }
      }
      if (payload.name === 'tv-widget-load') {
        if (id && payload.frameElementId === id) {
          onLoadedEvent?.()
        }
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('message', onNoDataAvailable)

    // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('message', onNoDataAvailable)
    }
  }, [id, onNoDataEvent, onLoadedEvent])
}

// Required to link to TradingView website for the widget
export const TradingViewLabel = ({ symbol, ...props }: { symbol: string } & FlexProps) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation()
  return (
    <Flex alignItems="center" px="24px" {...props}>
      <Link fontSize="14px" href={`https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/${symbol}`} external>
        BNB {t('Chart')}
      </Link>
      <Text fontSize="14px" ml="4px">
        {t('by')} TradingView
      </Text>
    </Flex>
  )
}

export default TradingView
```

I have also attempted to load TradingView using react-helmet-async by making use of:

```
<Helmet>
        <script src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js" type="text/javascript" id="tradingViewWidget" />
      </Helmet>
```

Which also didn't render.

Does anyone have any idea why this component might not be rendering?

I have attempted to render the Tradingview chart without making use of existing UI components which also isn't working.

I am also getting the following error upon inspection of Firefox's console:

Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).

Could this be causing the chart to not render?

Call made to the TradingView component in an attempt to render a chart:

```
import TradingViewChart from 'components/TradingView'
import React from 'react'

const TRADING_VIEW_COMPONENT_ID = 'tradingview_b239c'

const TradingView = () => {
  return <TradingViewChart id={TRADING_VIEW_COMPONENT_ID} symbol="BINANCE:BNBUSDT" />
}

export default TradingView
```